# Avoid going below index -1 with a for loop

Tags: java, algorithm

How do I avoid going below 0 with this for loop ? When this loop executes, it checks  if both the vehicle and the garage are in the same space. If not, it decrements the vehicle loop by `--i` to get the next available vehicle. when it reaches to `index 0`, it is going below `index -1` causing the program to crash.

```
for (int i = vehicles.size() - 1; i >= 0;) {
        for (int j = 0; j < garage.size();) {
            if (this.garage.get(j).getSpace() == this.vehicles.get(i).getSpace()) {
                if (this.garage.get(j).garageRequest(vehicles.get(i).getvehiclesType())
                        && this.garage.get(j).getLimit() > 0) {
                    this.garage.get(j).addvehicles(vehicles.get(i));
                    this.vehicles.remove(i);
                    i--;

                    break;
                } else {
                    j++;
                }
            } else {

                i--;
                j = 0;

            }

        }
```

i tried the following at the end

```
else if(i != 0) {
         i--;
         j = 0;

        }
```

Comment: Only change your loop variables in the `for (...)` statement. You are modifying your outer loop variable in your inner loop.

Comment: @tgdavies the i-- is outside to make it decrement if the vehicle and the garage is not at the same space.

Comment: Please try to implement this code with enhance for loop instead of this loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second condition to your inner loop. That is, change

```
for (int j = 0; j < garage.size();) {
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < garage.size() && i >= 0;) {
```